# Minor styling issue on edit preview for H3 headings

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, user-interface

There's a discrepancy between how third-level headers (`### Heading`) are displayed in actual posts versus in the preview. (Normal display being IMO better, the other heading levels look consistent.)

I'm seeing this on Chromium 22.0 (Linux), looks about the same on Firefox 10 and IE 9:

#### Preview

> [image]

#### Actual post

> [image]

(For a live demo, just click `Edit` on this post.)

Looks like the CSS `.wmd-preview h3` rule is overriding `font-weight` from `bold` to `normal`.

This is very minor, but it's nice to have a consistent preview when you're trying to get a post to look good.
Could it be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fix will be in the next production build.